# Consolidating Multiple Solo 401k Plans into One

Tags: united-states, 401k, solo-401k

My spouse and I have separate solo 401k plans (let’s call them Plan A and Plan B), which we opened a few years ago when we undertook self-employed activities. This year, we opened an LLC as QJV and are looking to consolidate those solo 401k plans into one (let’s call it Plan C).

Furthermore, after some research, it seems that in community property states, we’re considered a Controlled Group and can only have one solo 401k plan. However, we have two solo 401k plans and need to fix this as soon as possible.

We are trying to understand the best course of action.

Option #1:

1. Adopt a new solo 401k plan (Plan C)
2. Perform trustee-trustee transfers from Plan A and B to the new Plan C
3. Close the old solo 401k plans (Plans A and B)

Option #2:

1. Amend (restate) Plan A so it becomes Plan C
2. Perform a trustee-trustee transfer from Plan B to the new Plan C
3. Close solo 401k plan (Plan B)

Option #3:

Create a controlled group plan, which will list both Plan A and Plan B in the solo 401(k) plan documents (Plan C).

It seems like Option #1 is the simplest one, but I’m unsure if it’s ok to do it. Option #2 acts as a middle ground, but its benefits compared to Option #1 aren’t very clear to me. Option #3 appears to be the most complex.

Can we go with Option #1 in our case?

Comment: You've listed the options, and the considerations, so what's your question? Do you want someone to make the decision for you?

Comment: @littleadv, the question is if we can go with Option #1 in our case

Comment: You can go with any of the options, that's why they're options... My advice would be to consult a specialist - a CPA/EA/Attorney who's specializing on retirement plans.

Comment: If the question is "can we", yes. If the question is "should we", that depends on the exact details of the plans involved plus your own preferences. And there's a fourth option: leave things as they are, and just make sure each plan has the partner listed as beneficiary in case of death.

Comment: You don't have *a* QJV, you have two entirely unrelated businesses. Claiming that it's one business so your spouse can put some of your earnings into their Solo 401K is income tax fraud. If you don't like the advice of random strangers on the internet, go hire a pro.

Comment: @nobody who said those are two entirely unrelated businesses?

Comment: I suspect @nobody refers to [this](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/156831/2998). Note that while spousal income counts for IRA, it does not for 401k, and community property rules don't mater here. If you're the only one with earned income - you'll be the only one with contributions to 401k, regardless of the ownership structure.

Comment: @littleadv, it is wrong. a single business can consist of many activities. Both of us have passed the 500 hours of participation test for QJV and we can contribute to a 401k(s). And yes, the professionals (3 business tax attorneys) nobody referred us to stated the same: we use one account, perform activities related to our business for its success, and there is nothing wrong with paying SE taxes as 50/50 and contributing 50/50.

Comment: @illuminato since we don't know the real facts and the attorneys (I hope) do you should follow the guidance of your attorneys. That said, your comment contradicts what you described in the previous question I linked to. So if you tell the attorneys what you think they need to hear to give you the answers you want instead of the actual facts then you may end up having a big problem.